# uci heart dataset cleaveland prediction column has more than 2 values (0 and 1). What is the meaning of this?

Tags: prediction

I'm using R with decision tree algorithm for UCI heart dataset Cleaveland prediction column has more than 2 values (0 and 1) like 0,1,2,3,4. What is the meaning of this?

following are the description of attributes file of the dataset.

Attribute Information:

```
  ****-- 14. #58 (num)       (the predicted attribute)****
```

58 num: diagnosis of heart disease (angiographic disease status)
        -- Value 0: < 50% diameter narrowing
        -- Value 1: > 50% diameter narrowing
        (in any major vessel: attributes 59 through 68 are vessels)

10. Class Distribution:
        Database:      0   1   2   3   4 Total
          Cleveland: 164  55  36  35  13   303
          Hungarian: 188  37  26  28  15   294
        Switzerland:   8  48  32  30   5   123
      Long Beach VA:  51  56  41  42  10   200

Comment: Are you referring to this dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease ? Then download the "Data Set Description" from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and precious time. Yes, I downloaded both the dataset and attribute description files but I'm unable to understand the last column(num-column number:14).Could you kindly explain the last column of the dataset what it describes, here is the link:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.cleveland.data